# Here API returning very poorly constructed routes for transit

Tags: routes, here-api

I am trying to use the Here API for my transit app. My target is to find an efficient transit plan for point A to point B. I was trying, for example, to find a route from Trafalgar Square (coordinates `51.5080° N, 0.1281° W`) to Madam Tussauds (`51.5230° N, 0.1544° W`). So, this is the URL I tried:

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=pedestrian&origin=51.5308,0.12&destination=51.5323,0.15&return=summary&apiKey=myKey

In response I get a very poorly constructed route, with just two sections - one for origin and one for destination. Same goes when I try `car` in place of `pedestrian`. In contrast, when I use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=trafalgar%20square%20to%20madame%20tussauds), for example, I get a detailed route, saying `"Go from A to B for 500 metres, turn right at Torrington Palace, walk for 400 metres, cross the street to Paddington Avenue"`, etc.

[image]

Is there any way to get a similarly rich route information for place A to B with Here APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maneuver details in routing V8 are returned by specifying the following parameters in the request.

```
return=polyline,actions,instructions
```

The structured information about the actions needed to complete the route can be obtained by specifying return=polyline,actions when requesting a route. This may be useful when providing user interface elements such as the position or icon for an action.

Instructions may be included in an action by specifying return=polyline,actions,instructions when requesting the route. Instructions provide a textual description of the action that is appropriate for end-users.

Example Request:

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?
origin=51.5080,0.1281&
transportMode=car&
destination=51.5230,0.1544&
return=polyline,actions,instructions,summary&
apikey=<API KEY>
```

Response:
[image]

The request can be mocked up here:
https://refclient.ext.here.com/#url=https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=51.5080,0.1281&transportMode=car&destination=51.5230,0.1544&return=polyline,actions,instructions,summary&apikey=SQJ15KMgNuP6jvYPiLSG_-aics8s7f55XPwOhSfXeYM

Documentation Link: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/actions.html

Comment: Thanks. I will award the bounty, since this solves my problem. One question - how fine grained are the directions? For example, if used on a mobile app, the API will receive the coordinates given by GPS. Somebody may be standing at one point, and the ideal route should be X. Somebody may be standing just 100 feet apart, and the route for him may be Y. The difference in coordinates will be puny, but it will be there. Will HERE API be able to give the correct routes for the two separate but close scenarios?

Comment: The directions are always up to date. The minimum distance is 1 meter between source and destination to calculate routes.